# Best practice to 'combine' jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of creating a customized filter plugin for jQuery.

So far' I've managed to implement the following code:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.filterbyDate = function (filterValue) {
        var tableDate = new Date($(':eq(3)', $(val)).text());
        var days = numDaysBetween(tableDate, new Date());

        if (filterValue === "-1") {
            $(val).show();
        } else {
            switch (filterValue) {

                case "This Week":
                    if (days > 7) {
                        $(val).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(val).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case "This Month":
                    if (days > 30) {
                        $(val).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(val).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case "This Year":
                    if (days > 365) {
                        $(val).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(val).show();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.filterbyClient = function (filterValue) {
        var $table = $(".tablefilter");

    $.each($table.find("tbody>tr"), function (ind, val) {
        var name = $(':eq(2)', $(val)).text();

        if (filterValue === "-1") {
            $(val).show();
        } else {
            if (name.trim() !== filterValue) {
                $(val).hide();
            } else {
                $(val).show();
            }
        }
    });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

It's implemented by:

```
controller1.filterByDate(date);
controller2.filterByClient(client);
```

This works exactly as it should separately, but when I try 'filterByClient' after 'filterByDate', it naturally overwrites the former for the latter.
So essentially I would like to `filterByClient` based on the results on `filterByDate`

Is there any best practice for somehow 'combining' methods where need be, to filter only on the latest results?

**Note:** The methods are called by two different controllers (select lists)

**Eg:**

```
    $("#dateFilter").change(function () {
        $(this).filterbyDate($(this).val());
    });

    $("#clientFilter").change(function() {
        $(this).filterbyClient($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: That very much depends on what `do stuff` is. If you did just return a [`filter`ed](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) collection, it would be working with chaining. But they seem to modify some external things (or: the same external thing) using side effects? Not a good idea.

Comment: Could you show an example of *"when I try 'filterByClient' after 'filterByDate'"*? If that means chaining, I don't see how you would even do that with two different controllers (whatever those are).

Comment: `//Do Stuff` Shows / Hides table rows based on the selection

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Ok, and how is that different from calling them "separately"?

Comment: @Juhana I don't think I know what you mean? I can call either of the filters at any time, in any order.

Comment: Wait, I think I see what you're getting at. You want that the table is filtered by both filters at the same time. Well, you'd have to show what the methods actually do for anyone to give an answer. It's not something that has a universal answer applicable to every plugin.

Comment: Specifically, you need to show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to minify it, but I've added what it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method chaining. Just `return this;` at the end of your functions and use them like `controller.filterByDate(date).filterByClient(client);`

So your methods would look like

```
$.fn.filterbyDate = function (filterValue) {
    //Do Stuff
    return this;
};

$.fn.filterbyClient = function (filterValue) {
    // Do Stuff
    return this;
};
```

EDIT:

If its used by different controllers, you have to abstract your controllers, so that the methods don't have to filter the controllers itself, but a list which they use.

So you can do something like:

```
var list = controller1.list.filterByDate(date);
controller2.list = list.filterByClient(client);
```

Comment: The `filterByDate` and `filterByClient` are called by two different controllers. Should of made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the list to be filtered as an argument to your function:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.filterbyDate = function (list, filterValue) {
    var filteredList = [];
    //apply filter on list and put result into filteredList...
    return filteredList;
};

$.fn.filterbyClient = function (list, filterValue) {
    var filteredList = [];
    //apply filter on list and put result into filteredList...
    return filteredList;
};

}(jQuery));

var entireList = [...];
var filterdList = controller1.filterByDate(entireList, date);
var doubleFilteredList = controller2.filterByClient(filterdList , client);
```

**Update:**

Or merge your filter functions into 1 and allow multiple fields to be filtered at once:

```
$.fn.filterby = function (options) {
        //apply filters
         if (options.date !== undefined) {
        //     apply date filter based on value of options.date
         }
         if (options.client !== undefined) {
        //     apply client filter on value of options.client 
         }
    };
```

Comment: So create lists to show/hide on my table, instead of show/hiding them in the methods themselves? I'll try run with this.